Character not rendering the pause letter in the Quran in Arabic correctly
Note: Sorry, I'm writing via translate because my English is bad.
I'm developing an app using Flutter. I am having a character problem with the Arabic pause letter in the Holy Quran. When I copy the Arabic word on the site and paste it somewhere, it does not appear as it is on the site. It looks broken. I made a screen recording of this, watch it. https://youtu.be/NeIvuVrDXqI
I want it written like this:



But it's written this way:



I changed the font, changed the system language, tried all kinds of ways, but I could not solve the problem.

To clarify: are VS Code and Microsoft Office also showing the wrong result? What environments show the correct result? Have you tried a different computer/OS?

Please provide the actual string you are trying to display. It looks like you accidentally inserted U+06EC ARABIC ROUNDED HIGH STOP WITH FILLED CENTRE instead of the character you meant to use.

Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve]. Please do not use (sole) images of code/data/errors in your [mcve].
Copy the actual text, paste it into the question, then format it as code.

@nneonneo I tried it on ubuntu and windows 11 but I got the same error.

I did not add U+06EC. When I copy اُو۬لٰٓئِكَ in https://www.islamveihsan.com/abese-suresi-42-ayet-meali-arapca-yazilisi-anlami-ve-tefsiri.html, و۬ automatically appears like this.

The problem is not only in vscode, the same problem occurs everywhere. When you copy the word I mentioned from the site and paste it anywhere, the same problem occurs. I made a screen recording regarding this, you can watch it. https://youtu.be/NeIvuVrDXqI

Please provide the code sample here as text.

The string “اُو۬لٰٓئِكَ” that you copied does in fact contain U+06EC on top of the و. It is being rendered exactly as intended. However, the font that is being used to display this text on islamveihsan.com (Shaikh Hamdullah Basic) is faulty. It incorrectly substitutes the intended circle glyph for U+06EC with a different, unrelated symbol.

Is U+10EFE ARABIC SMALL LOW WORD QASR (see https://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U10EC0.pdf) the correct symbol by any chance?

@CharlotteBuff My problem was solved. Thank you very much bro.

@CharlotteBuff Is there a font you can recommend to me, such as Scheherazade, where all characters with computer lines work without any problems?

The Noto Arabic fonts (Kufi, Naskh, and Sans) properly support all Arabic characters in the current version of Unicode: https://notofonts.github.io/#arabic

Most Quranic texts use 'أُو۟لَـٰۤىِٕكَ', but the version you are referencing uses an alternative annotation found in some Turkish Quran manuscripts. It was only added in Unicode 15.0 so support for it is limited. It appears the site you are using has repurposed another Arabic character and swapped glyphs.

So 'أُو۟لَـٰۤىِٕكَ' vsersus 'أُولَـٰۤىِٕكَ' . I'd be inclined to use one of the SIL Arabic fonts.
